# Error BTYD: pnbd.EstimateParameters: L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'

Tags: r, package

Using 
**> params <- pnbd.EstimateParameters(cal.cbs)**

from the BTYD package i get following error:

"**optim(logparams, pnbd.eLL, cal.cbs = cal.cbs, max.param.value = max.param.value, L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn**'".

What does this mean? What could be the reason for this error? My cbs(customer by sufficient statistic) matrix is 21394 3 large with the desired colums: x, t.x, T.cal.

Info cbs:

1. max(cal.cbs$x)=302
2. min(cal.cbs$x)=0
3. max(cal.cbs$t.x)=89
4. min(cal.cbs$t.x)=0
5. max(cal.cbs$T.cal)=89.57143
6. min(cal.cbs$T.cal)=0

Comment: you might try `bgnbd` instead. Fader et al developed it to be computationally simpler with similar results. I had this problem, but switched from `pnbd` to `bgnbd` and that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 4):

I spent some time to read and change the source code, and finally find out the computation error during the calculation of log likelihood and fixed. You can run the code below and call the pnbd.EstimateParameters.ori() function to try it again. It works for my case (I had exactly the same error as you have).

```
pnbd.cbs.LL.ori = 
function (params, cal.cbs) 
{
    dc.check.model.params(c("r", "alpha", "s", "beta"), params, 
        "pnbd.cbs.LL")
    tryCatch(x <- cal.cbs[, "x"], error = function(e) stop("Error in pnbd.cbs.LL: cal.cbs must have a frequency column labelled \"x\""))
    tryCatch(t.x <- cal.cbs[, "t.x"], error = function(e) stop("Error in pnbd.cbs.LL: cal.cbs must have a recency column labelled \"t.x\""))
    tryCatch(T.cal <- cal.cbs[, "T.cal"], error = function(e) stop("Error in pnbd.cbs.LL: cal.cbs must have a column for length of time observed labelled \"T.cal\""))
    if ("custs" %in% colnames(cal.cbs)) {
        custs <- cal.cbs[, "custs"]
    }
    else {
        custs <- rep(1, length(x))
    }
    return(sum(custs * pnbd.LL.ori(params, x, t.x, T.cal)))## changed
}


pnbd.LL.ori  = 
function (params, x, t.x, T.cal) 
{
    max.length <- max(length(x), length(t.x), length(T.cal))
    if (max.length%%length(x)) 
        warning("Maximum vector length not a multiple of the length of x")
    if (max.length%%length(t.x)) 
        warning("Maximum vector length not a multiple of the length of t.x")
    if (max.length%%length(T.cal)) 
        warning("Maximum vector length not a multiple of the length of T.cal")
    dc.check.model.params(c("r", "alpha", "s", "beta"), params, 
        "pnbd.LL")
    if (any(x < 0) || !is.numeric(x)) 
        stop("x must be numeric and may not contain negative numbers.")
    if (any(t.x < 0) || !is.numeric(t.x)) 
        stop("t.x must be numeric and may not contain negative numbers.")
    if (any(T.cal < 0) || !is.numeric(T.cal)) 
        stop("T.cal must be numeric and may not contain negative numbers.")
    x <- rep(x, length.out = max.length)
    t.x <- rep(t.x, length.out = max.length)
    T.cal <- rep(T.cal, length.out = max.length)
    r <- params[1]
    alpha <- params[2]
    s <- params[3]
    beta <- params[4]
    maxab <- max(alpha, beta)
    absab <- abs(alpha - beta)
    param2 <- s + 1
    if (alpha < beta) {
        param2 <- r + x
    }
    part1 <- r * log(alpha) + s * log(beta) - lgamma(r) + lgamma(r + 
        x)
    part2 <- -(r + x) * log(alpha + T.cal) - s * log(beta + T.cal)
    if (absab == 0) {
        F1 <- -(r + s + x) * log(maxab + t.x)
        F2 <- -(r + s + x) * log(maxab + T.cal)
        partF <- subLogs.ori(F1, F2)## changed
    }
    else {
        F1 <- hyperg_2F1(r + s + x, param2, r + s + x + 1, absab/(maxab + 
            t.x))/((maxab + t.x)^(r + s + x))
        F2 <- hyperg_2F1(r + s + x, param2, r + s + x + 1, absab/(maxab + 
            T.cal))/((maxab + T.cal)^(r + s + x))
        partF <- log(F1 - F2)
    }

    part3 <- log(s) - log(r + s + x) + partF
    ## modified
    result = part1+ part2+ log(1 + exp(part3 - part2))
    return(result)
}



subLogs.ori = 
function (loga, logb) 
{
## this function is modified
    myvec = loga - logb
    sel = myvec <30
    result = rep(0,length(myvec))
    result[sel] = logb[sel] + log(exp(loga[sel] - logb[sel]) - 1)
    result[!sel] = loga[!sel]
    return(result)

}




pnbd.EstimateParameters.ori = function (cal.cbs, par.start = c(1, 1, 1, 1), max.param.value = 10000) 
{
    dc.check.model.params(c("r", "alpha", "s", "beta"), par.start, 
        "pnbd.EstimateParameters")
    pnbd.eLL <- function(params, cal.cbs, max.param.value) {
        params <- exp(params)
        params[params > max.param.value] <- max.param.value
        return(-1 * pnbd.cbs.LL.ori(params, cal.cbs))## changed
    }
    logparams <- log(par.start)
    results <- optim(logparams, pnbd.eLL, cal.cbs = cal.cbs, 
        max.param.value = max.param.value, method = "L-BFGS-B")
    estimated.params <- exp(results$par)
    estimated.params[estimated.params > max.param.value] <- max.param.value
    return(estimated.params)
}


params <- pnbd.EstimateParameters.ori(cal.cbs)
```

Comment: Can you explain what the error you found in the estimation code was? Is it just a check for x < T.cal as you mentioned in your other answer, or was it something else?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I tried to run your code but error occurred: function hyperg_2F1 not found. Do you have the code for this function?

Comment: You can find `hyperg_2F1` in package **gsl**, see [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gsl/versions/2.1-1/topics/Hyperg). Just install the package, put `gsl::` in front of the function call (i.e. `gsl::hyperg_2F1`; note that the function occurs twice!) and re-run the code.

Comment: I also faced the same problem. But using the modified function throw another error which is 
    ` Error in pnbd.cbs.LL.ori(params, cal.cbs) : 
      could not find function "pnbd.cbs.LL.ori" ` 
@fdetsch

Comment: @AashishGulabani The function is defined in the very first line of the above code chunk.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
R> cal.cbs1 = subset(cal.cbs, x<100)

R> params <- pnbd.EstimateParameters(cal.cbs1)
```

Supposedly there should be no customers make more purchases (x) than the number of days (T.cal) he/she has been observed, because the algorithm assume each user could only make at most one purchase per day. If one user make more than two purchase, the dc.MergeTransactionsOnSameDate function should merge them to one purchase per day. So just try first with small x.

Also I do believe there is some computational bug with the pnbd.EstimateParaters() function as it called the optim() function in R. The error message you see is from the optim() function.

Answer (score 0):

The function is getting fail for large datasets. So, there is a patched version of the BTYD package called BTYD2. It is not on CRAN, you need to build the package before using in R.

https://github.com/ghuiber/BTYD2

Using patched version of the BTYD package solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, change into the code source:

```
trace("bgnbd.EstimateParameters",edit=TRUE)
```

Second, change the method:

In the following code:

```
       function (cal.cbs, par.start = c(1, 3, 1, 3), max.param.value = 10000) 
{
  dc.check.model.params(c("r", "alpha", "a", "b"), par.start, 
    "bgnbd.EstimateParameters")
  bgnbd.eLL <- function(params, cal.cbs, max.param.value) {
    params <- exp(params)
    params[params > max.param.value] = max.param.value
    return(-1 * bgnbd.cbs.LL(params, cal.cbs))
  }
  logparams = log(par.start)
  results = optim(logparams, bgnbd.eLL, cal.cbs = cal.cbs, 
    max.param.value = max.param.value, method = "BFGS")  # j ai changé cela (I change the methode )
  estimated.params <- exp(results$par)
  estimated.params[estimated.params > max.param.value] <- max.param.value
  return(estimated.params)
}
```